# Split File and Process each part while using a shared resource

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-integration, splitter

I am using spring integration for polling a file. This single file contains multiple reports. I want to split the file into report files and save as different files.

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"
        directory="file:${fileInDirectory}" 
        filename-pattern="*.txt" 
        prevent-duplicates="true">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000"/>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="filesIn"
                                   output-channel="filesOut"
                                   ref="handler"/>

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut"
                                   directory="file:${archiveDirectory}"
                                   delete-source-files="true"/>
```

Inside the handler, handling method inside handler is like following.

```
public List<ReportContent> splitTextToReports(File file){ 
     // split the file
     // store the file content text to ReportContent object
     // add to a List of ReportContent
}
```

**ReportContent** has following fields

- reportData (the text that will be saved in new file)
- reportType
- reportDate

There is another processing that is required for each ReportContent.

- Look up report path to save the report, based on the report type. This is done through a service call.
- Save report data in a table

Following is the method that will process each element of the list returned in the above method.

```
public void processReportContent (ReportContent reportContent){
   // process report content and save the file in the relevant place
}
```

Two parts to the question.

1. How to use a splitter to take over just after first master File is read. So that processing of each report can be done part of splitted objects.
2. The Service that look up report path should use a common HashMap between all splitted objects. If a value based on the report type exists in this hash map, it will retrieve from this map. Otherwise a separate API call should be executed to retrieve the report path using the report type. Report type and the value (report) received from this API call will be stored in the map. The importance of Map is to avoid making unnecessary API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process items in parallel there always was a trick for `<splitter>` like the downstream `ExecutorChannel`, so during the iteration of the splitted items we move to the next one immediately after sending the previous.

In addition for better throughput the `splitter` support `Iterator` for streaming.

I was going to suggest the `FileSplitter` for your task, but I guess that you don't split by lines, but by some other identificator. Maybe your content is just XML or JSON, which allows to determine part of the content enough easy.

From here that might not be so easy to provide some `Iterator` implementation for your case.

However I guess it doesn't matter. You have already the split logic and builds your `List<ReportContent>`.

Regarding the `ConcurrentMap`.

How about to take a look into the `@Cacheable` Spring support for your "hard" service, when the next call for the same key will just return the value from cache?

For this purpose you can use the `directory-expression` on the `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>`:

```
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter directory-expression="@reportPathService.getPath(payload)" />
```

The same technique you can accept for the file name as well.

Note: pay attention to the default header for the file name: `FileHeaders.FILENAME`.

Comment: yeah, your idea fixed the issue. But I have a new query. Grateful if you can give some idea. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775105/spring-integration-inbound-file-endpoint-how-to-process-a-file-correctly

Answer (score 2):

1.
Instead of `<int:service-activator input-channel="filesIn"...` I would add a chain

```
<int:chain id="processor" input-channel="filesIn" output-channel="filesOut">
    <int:splitter>
        <bean class="...your impl of org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter..."/>
    </int:splitter>
</int:chain>
```

and move your `splitTextToReports` logic into this splitter impl. So in the chain after the splitter you'll have a flat stream of `ReportContent` instances.

2.
add transform step in the chain after splitter. Put your `processReportContent` logic here. The result of transformation: string with your report in payload, and file name in 'filename' message header variable.

API of your transformer may be like this

```
interface ReportContentTransformer {
   Message<?> transform(ReportContent content);
}
```

The chain will be looks like

```
<int:chain id="processor" input-channel="filesIn" output-channel="filesOut">
    <int:splitter>
       ...
    </int:splitter>
    <int:transformer ref="...ref on your ReportContentTransformer interface implementation bean..." method="transform"/>
</int:chain>
```

3.
add to your `outbound-channel-adapter` attribute

```
filename-generator-expression="headers.get('filename')"
```

to use file name from `filename` variable while file storing.