# Spring Integration - Inbound file endpoint. How to process a file correctly.

Tags: java, spring, file, integration, spring-integration

I have a Spring integration flow as following.

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"
        directory="file:${incomingDir}" 
        filename-pattern="*.txt" 
        prevent-duplicates="true">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000"/>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:splitter input-channel="filesIn" 
        ref="filesSplitterService"
        method="splitFilesToReportContent"
        output-channel="reportProcessIn"
     />

     <int:channel id="reportProcessIn"/>

     <int:chain input-channel="reportProcessIn" output-channel="reportProcessOut">    
        <int:service-activator ref="reportProcessorService" method="readReportMetaData" />
        <int:service-activator ref="reportProcessorService" method="saveReportFileInFileSystem" />
        <int:service-activator ref="reportProcessorService" method="saveReportMetaDataInDB" />
    </int:chain>

     <int:channel id="reportProcessOut"/>


    <bean id="filesSplitterService" class="com.app.integration.FilesSplitter"/>

    <bean id="reportProcessorService" class="com.app.reporting.integration.ReportProcessor"/>
```

Incoming file is splitted by one service and make a List of **ReportContent**.

Then service chain takes each element of the **ReportContent** and works on them to read_report_meta_data from the file content (like report id, report type), save report content string to a file in the appropriate directory, and save report meta data in a database. The flow is working fine except there seems to have a loose end.

I get the following exception.

> org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher
>   has no subscribers

1. I don't need to aggregate the splitted elements. Flow is completed as far as I am concerned after saving meta data in the database.
2. However I would like to move the original file, the master file I splitted into report files, to some other directory after working with it. How could I incorporate that logic? File:outbound-channel seems to be the way to do it, but I don't understand how to.
3. Is there a way to avoid saveReportFileInSystem and saveReportMetaDataInDB operations based on some meta-data read in readReportMetaData operation.

For convenience, I have given below the structure of my service classes.

class : FilesSplitter

```
public List<ReportContent> splitFilesToReportContent(File file){
}
```

class : ReportProcessor

```
public ReportContent readReportMetaData(ReportContent reportContent) {


}



public ReportContent saveReportFileInFileSystem(ReportContent reportContent) {


    }

public ReportContent saveReportMetaDataInDB(ReportContent reportContent) {


    }
```

One thing to note is that I am not using message headers. I didn't yet feel the necessity to use to but I am okay to use. I am new to spring integration so, any advice to improve this flow would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. I get the following exception... org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException**

I suppose you have missed `file:outbound-channel-adapter` definition here.

**2. However I would like to move the original file, the master file I splitted into report files, to some other directory after working with it. How could I incorporate that logic?**

As written in [14.3.4 File Outbound Channel Adapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-outbound-channel-adapter) your should use `delete-source-files` attribute for `outbound-channel-adapter` but(!)

> ...attribute will only have an effect if the inbound Message has a File payload or if the FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE header value contains either the source File instance or a String representing the original file path.

So, in you `reportProcessorService` you should deal with raw messages anyway. You don't have source file as a payload anymore. Thus, only one option is to set properly `FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE` header value.

**3. Is there a way to avoid saveReportFileInSystem and saveReportMetaDataInDB operations based on some meta-data read in readReportMetaData operation?**

Yes, there is. Use after `readReportMetaData` in the chain EIP either [PayloadTypeRouter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-payloadtyperouter) (if it's possible becorse its simple) or [Configuring (Generic) Router](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-namespace)

Answer (score 3):

We usually have `Dispatcher has no subscribers` when there is really no subscribers for the `SubscribableChannel` (like yours `reportProcessOut`) or those subscribers has been stopped, which can treat as a "no subscribers", too.

We usually recommend to the send the `<service-activator>` result to the `nullChannel`, if you aren't interested in that result. That is the case when you can't achieve your task with just standard one-way component - `<outbound-channel-adapter>`.

> However I would like to move the original file, the master file I splitted into report files,

You can do that with the second one-way subscriber for the `<publish-subscriber-channel>` as a `filesIn`. And achiever that with standard `File.renameTo()` function. I don't reason to blow your mind with something like `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>`. You are on the file system already. So, just use its capabilities. We need adapters for files, when we deal with remote files like FTP, SFTP.

You can use `Map<String, Object> headers` as a second parameter for your 3service methods and Framework will inject the proper object for you from the request `Message<?>`.

See @Andriy Kryvtsun 's answer regarding "avoid saveReportFileInSystem".

As an alternative you can use the `<filter>` to skip and drop messages which should not be saved by some reason.

Comment: interesting... is `nullChannel` a predefined channel name?

Comment: Yes, it is. See `DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.registerNullChannel()`

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-special-channels